# How to open .xlsx file on UIWebView in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiwebview, xlsx

Is it possible to open the .xlsx file on `UIWebView`. I can't open .xlsx file on `UIWebView`. I got the following error message when I open the .xlsx file.

> Unable to Read Document. An error occurred while reading the document.

I didn't face any issue when I open remaining file types like .xls, .doc, .txt and .pdf.

Comment: No, and you should have found an answer to this ander in: a. the documentation of Apple or: b. by search this site. Next time put some effort in research.

Comment: @rckoenes, But I can view the .xlsx file on safari browser. I attached the .xlsx file on gmail and open in the iPhone browser. Here safari browser supported .xlsx file. I can view the .xlsx file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.xlsx cannot be opened in UIWebView, you can use .xls - it will work fine.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yeah. There is no issue when i open remaining files. But problem is I need to open .xlsx file. Is there any other way?

Comment: Is there any official document for this?

Comment: Outdated answer - now xlsx could be loaded by url

Answer (score 1):

You can open .xlsx

```
[webView loadData:urlData MIMEType:@"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" textEncodingName:@"utf-8" baseURL:nil];
```

Swift

```
webView.load(urlData, mimeType: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", textEncodingName: "utf-8", baseURL: nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

One way you can solve this is using html's power by embedding the content inside html.

```
func loadDataContent(data:Data,mimeType:String) {
    let htmlContent = "<iframe width=\"100%\" height=\"100%\" src=\"data:\(mimeType);base64,\(data.base64EncodedString())\"></iframe>"
    webBrowser?.loadHTMLString(htmlContent, baseURL: nil)
}
```

-

For Microsoft Excel Files you can do something like:

.xlsx extension:

```
loadDataContent(data: data, mimeType: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet")
```

.xls extension:

```
loadDataContent(data: data, mimeType: "application/vnd.ms-excel")
```

Reference to other mime types:
https://filext.com/faq/office_mime_types.html