# Load xlsx or xls into a webview

Tags: swift, excel

I have edited an Excel file and have it as NSData. I want to convert this xlsx to PDF and have read that if I succed to put it into a webview as NSData, I'm home safe. I can't succeed with this, all I get is that the webview tries to open it as text.

I tried:

```
webview.load(picData as Data, mimeType: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.template", characterEncodingName: "", baseURL: NSURL() as URL)
```

with xlsx and:

```
webview.load(picData as Data, mimeType: "application/vnd.ms-excel", characterEncodingName: "", baseURL: NSURL() as URL).
```

Even tho I specify the textencoding with utf-8 it will create the same outcome. I have no problem opening the excel from the bundle but after I download a excel file and use it as Nsdata I cant load it into a webview.

So basicly I need to take a excel as Nsdata and load it into a webview.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to open .xlsx file on UIWebView in iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11139284/how-to-open-xlsx-file-on-uiwebview-in-iphone)

Comment: Since the accepted answer on the "possible dublicate" is wrong since the documentation is stating that you can read xlsx files. Plus im downloading the file into Nsdata before im loading the excel file.

Comment: "The documentation" do you have a link? Regardless, it's the same question (hence the duplicate). Also the second answer has different code from yours, so try that.

Comment: The big thing is that im loading the excelfile as Nsdata while the other question is loading locally. I know that the answer you are referring to is using utf-8 instead of "". I doesnt change my outcome.

Comment: The API you and the second answer are using is the same...`urlData` would be `Data`. just downloaded from a URL

Comment: I hardly belive that we use the same API and I dont understand why that would matter. You have been redirecting me to some unrelevant information and arent helping me, if you are doing this for stackoverflow points I can give upvotes. But aslong you dont Know What you are talking about please stop.

Comment: ...how would I be getting points for comments? You are using `webView.load`, they are using `webView.load`. That's the Application Programming Interface that you are both using. You don't have "UTF-8" as your `characterEncodingName`, and you provided 0 documentation on why the accepted answer is wrong. Sorry for trying to help.

Comment: I came here because I had a problem. I hoped that someone had the similar problem since it's a normal thing to edit a xlsx and then convert it to a pdf. I didn't ask the question because people could guess what the problem was. I didnt specify my characterEcodingName since it doens't matter in this instance. And I didn't set my baseurl to nil since it needs a value.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a late answer, we had similar issue in one of our projects, one way you can solve this is using html's power by embedding the content inside html.

```
func loadDataContent(data:Data,mimeType:String) {
    let htmlContent = "<iframe width=\"100%\" height=\"100%\" src=\"data:\(mimeType);base64,\(data.base64EncodedString())\"></iframe>"
    webBrowser?.loadHTMLString(htmlContent, baseURL: nil)
}
```

-

For Microsoft Excel Files you can do something like:

.xlsx extension:

```
loadDataContent(data: data, mimeType: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet")
```

.xls extension:

```
loadDataContent(data: data, mimeType: "application/vnd.ms-excel")
```

Reference to other mime types:
https://filext.com/faq/office_mime_types.html

Answer (score 0):

The code that I had worked fine but I had to save the nsdata locally before loading it to the webview.

Answer (score -1):

```
override public func viewDidLoad() 
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    webView.loadFileURL(fileURLPreview, allowingReadAccessTo: fileURLPreview)
}
```

Comment: Please try to explain why you chose this route or the logic that makes this work to benefit OP and all other future readers. Code dumps may solve the problem, but do little when it comes to learning anything.